# Implementing repositories with EF database first (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I've only read articles about implementing repositories with a code first approach - are there any examples out there regarding the repository pattern applied to a database first / EDMX type data layer?

I guess the ideal situation would to be separate domain and data layers with the generated entity classes mapped to my domain / POCOs somehow.

Comment: It shouldn't matter much which approach is used. In the end it's only about contexts and sets. But I'm afraid this question is off-topic here. (Not a specific programming problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Repository Pattern in code first approach and also database first - it doesn't matter which approach you will choose.